# no outside internet access from machine

Tags: ubuntu, curl, nslookup

Running multiple ubuntu machines.

everytime I curl something I get a
curl(6) could not resolve host: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

nslookup gives me a time out

apt-get update fails with error:
Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

So seems like a dns error. Mind you the machine has been working flawlessly for a while with no issues. This started to pop up a few days ago. I go online and follow all the steps I could find to fix dns issues. Disabled IP6, updated hosts. Everything I could find. Still nothing. Oh maybe it's something upstream on your network, turns out the other machines I have on the network also running ubuntu work just fine. Only one. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If connect the machine straight to the modem with no router, still doesn't work.

Comment: I you are able to ping IP (like ***8.8.8.8***) then you have a DNS problem.<br>
On Ubuntu edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` by adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Are you still able to browse to websites?

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to provide some more informations in order for anybody to be able to help you.

Like, what Ubuntu version are you using?

Are you able to ping hostnames? or at least ping IPs? or nothing at all?

What is your resolv.conf file content?

What is the output of `ip a` for that server?

What is your firewall status and current configuration?